# Optimizing a humbly large node.js response

Tags: node.js, spray-client

I am responding with a large (10 MB) payload from node.js to an Akka spray.io based actor, and getting a chunk size error from spray/akka `[akka://spray-actor-system/user/IO-HTTP/group-0/3] Received illegal response: HTTP chunk size exceeds the configured limit of 1048576 bytes`.

My node.js code just plainly sends off the response in one `res.end` command. (It does so because the response is generated in a non-streamed way and therefore there has been no "inherent" gain in streaming it further along, at least up until a spray.io client-side was added).

I am wondering what's the simplest way to chunk the response using node.js api, in case I prefer not handling very large http responses by increasing the spray.io size limit. Also whether there's any performance downside in sending responses this size from node.js - i.e. does node.js block on the res.end operation?

Comment: The easiest way is to stream the response from source. Where does the response come from?